# Why isn't my C++ assembly signed?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, clr, assembly-signing

I have a C++ project, set to `/clr`, which is referenced by C# projects in the same solution. Unfortunately, it seems the C++ doesn't get properly signed, leading to the error message "assembly doesn't have a strong name." (`sn.exe` agrees with that error.)
However, there *is* an snk file in the project settings (Linker/Advanced), so it *should* be signed. Further, all project settings seem to be the same as in another C++ project in the same solution - where everything works.

The one thing I have found after tearing my hair over this for hours:
When eliminating the `/NOLOGO` switch for the linker, it becomes apparent that the linker is called *twice*. I don't have the slightest idea why that might be.
Now, in the project that works the linker gets passed the snk file in the command line (`/KEYFILE:`) for *both* invocations, in the one that does *not* work, the second invocation does *not* get the snk file passed.

Why would the linker be invoked twice? What determines that it doesn't get the snk file passed in the second invocation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution: Apparently, MS blew the SP1 release for VS2010 and you have to go and mess around in the MSBUild installation folder. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/11/10140139.aspx) is an article giving the dirty details.

(And why this would work in *one* project, but not in the other I have no idea. And, frankly, I've lost enough hours banging my head against this wall already, and will not investigate any further.)

Comment: Thanks for posting this. You saved me from hours of hair pulling.